# Offside--off whose side?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is more related to sport knowledge, but I need the meaning of the word. When in football we say

> someone is in offside

do we mean

> someone being off the side, meaning **out** of the side?

If so, what is the meaning of "side" here and whose side is meant?

Comment: What did you find when you looked up "[offside](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/offside)" in the dictionary, and why didn't that help?

Comment: You can read all about "offside" in this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offside_(association_football)

Comment: A player is not **in** offside. A player is offside (or not offside)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of "offside" is somewhat different between American football and "real" football (what Americans call soccer), but they both mean that a player has moved off their team's "side" of the field and into an area they are not permitted, or that they got to that part of the field in a way they weren't supposed to. (Hockey also has an offside penalty that is similar to the soccer usage.)